# Transfer paint from panel to panel

Tags: java, swing

I have two panels. The first one I draw on it using Graphics2d. I need a way to copy what I painted on panel 1 to panel 2 on MouseUp.I have did the painting part ,but I am stuck in copying it to the other panel.

Comment: Please tell and show more: 1) show your pertinent code, preferably as a valid [mcve], 2) show any attempt that you've made to perform your swap, 3) tell more of the details of what your program currently does and just exactly what you're trying to make it do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You could...

Store all the operations needed to generate the output in some kind of model, this model could then be provided to any other component which knew how to use it

## You could...

Use a `BufferedImage` to render the painting operations to in the first panel (painting the `BufferedImage`) and then simply make a copy it and pass it to the second (don't pass the original, otherwise you might run into unexpected issues)

## You could...

Use `JComponent#printAll` to paint the component to a `BufferedImage` and pass that to the second panel for it to paint

Comment: Examples of each of those suggestions can be found throughout SO, I suggest trying some and seeing what works for you and if you have a particular problem, then post another question with demonstrating the attempts you have made

Answer (score 1):

Paint to an off-screen image, then copy that image to both panels